# C - Find longest word in a sentence

Tags: c, text, input

Hi I have this program that reads a text file line by line and it's supposed to output the longest word in each sentence. Although it works to a degree, it's overwriting the biggest word with an equally big word which is something I am not sure how to fix. What do I need to think about when editing this program? Thanks

```
//Program Written and Designed by R.Sharpe
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include "memwatch.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char* sentence = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    while(fgets(sentence, 100, file) != NULL)
    {
        char* word;
        int maxLength = 0;
        char* maxWord;
        maxWord = (char*)calloc(40, sizeof(char));
        word = (char*)calloc(40, sizeof(char));
        word = strtok(sentence, " ");
        while(word != NULL)
        {
            //printf("%s\n", word);
            if(strlen(word) > maxLength)
            {
                maxLength = strlen(word);
                strcpy(maxWord, word);
            }
            word = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        printf("%s\n", maxWord);
        maxLength = 0; //reset for next sentence;
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

My textfile that the program is accepting contains this

```
some line with text 
another line of words 
Jimmy John took the a apple and something reallyreallylongword it was nonsense
```

and my output is this

```
text

another
reallyreallylongword
```

but I would like the output to be

```
some
another
reallyreallylongword
```

**EDIT: If anyone plans on using this code, remember when you fix the newline character issue don't forget about the null terminator. This is fixed by setting
sentence[strlen(sentence)-1] = 0 which in effect gets rid of newline character and replaces it with null terminating.**

Comment: `word = (char*)calloc(40, sizeof(char));` is a memory leak since on the next line you say `word = ...`.

Comment: Well I am allocating space for word by using calloc then I am assigning a value to the char* pointer right? How is that a memory leak?

Comment: Nope. You allocate some memory (`word` is your pointer to it). Then you say `word = ...` and so you've lot your pointer to the allocated memory. If you don't believe me just comment out the `calloc` and it will still work exactly the same ;-)

Comment: after `calloc()` `word` will point to the newly created memory, then right in the next line it is pointed to a different memory address returned by `strok`, hence the allocated memory is lost, and you didn't delete it anywhere

Comment: Suppose the first line was `Some line with text.` — would you want `text.` with the period counted as a word of length 5? If not, you need to add more delimiters to the `strtok()` calls — newlines, tabs, various punctuation characters. Things get tricky with single quotes; is `doesn't` one word or two? What about `He said, 'That is a line!'` where the single quotes are not really part of the words. You can make all sorts of reasonable decisions here, and it probably doesn't matter for the exercise you're working on as long as you're self-consistent (but is 'self-consistent' one or two words?).

Answer (score 5):

You get each line by using

```
fgets(sentence, 100, file)
```

The problem is, the new line character is stored inside `sentence`. For instance, the first line is `"some line with text\n"`, which makes the longest word `"text\n"`.

To fix it, remove the new line character every time you get `sentence`.

Comment: Or make the delimiter list include newline (and perhaps tab too, and maybe other characters).

Comment: I removed the '\n' character, what killed me later was that I think I also removed the null terminator as well which caused a lot of problems with seemingly correct looking code. Replacing newline with null terminator was replaced by doing sentence[(strlen(sentence)-1] = 0

Comment: @OP `sentence[(strlen(sentence)-1] = 0` has trouble too in rare situations where `strlen(sentence)` is `'\0'` like when a `'\0'` exists in a file after a `'\n'`.  Suggest @Jonathan Leffler modification to this solution.